# Parse XML into a Slider from a URL - Volusion

Tags: xml-parsing, jquery-slider, volusion

We are currently trying to implement a slider into the e-commerce software Volusion.

We would like to be able to port in several products including their name, price and picture dynamically as we want the information to change if a price changes.

I was on Volusion help chat with several Reps and one told me to use a CSV file, which does us no good due to having to download it every time a product changes. I did some digging of my own and found that Volusion allows us to use a URL to get some XML information back.

If anybody would be able to help being able to parse the information so I can get it setup in the slider I'd be grateful. I have provided the code below.

Thanks!

URL Example:

http://www.companyname.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=usr@companyname.com&EncryptedPassword=xxxx&EDI_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductName,pe.ProductPrice

XML Output Example:

```
<xmldata>
    <Products>
        <ProductName>ABC Widget</ProductName>
        <ProductPrice>4445545</ProductPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductName>XYZ Widget</ProductName>
        <ProductPrice>99494</ProductPrice>
    </Products>
</xmldata>
```

HTML:

```
<img class="arrow" src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/arrow-left.png">
<div class="product">
    <a href="#"><img src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/product-1.jpg"></a>
    <h4>Product Title and description</h4>
    <h5>$00.00</h5>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <a href="#"><img src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/product-1.jpg"></a>
    <h4>Product Title and description</h4>
    <h5>$00.00</h5>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <a href="#"><img src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/product-1.jpg"></a>
    <h4>Product Title and description</h4>
    <h5>$00.00</h5>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <a href="#"><img src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/product-1.jpg"></a>
    <h4>Product Title and description</h4>
    <h5>$00.00</h5>
</div>
<img class="arrow" src="vspfiles/templates/default/images/arrow-right.png">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Insert URL",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        $(xml).find('Products').each(function(){
            var $p = $(this);
            var pId =  $p.find('ProductId').text();

            var html = 'Testing: ' + pId + '<br />';

            $('#output').append($(html));
        });

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: One more thing, I'm well aware in the Javascript that it says #output. I do have a div called output for testing purposes.

Comment: What part of your code doesn't work? Also, what are you using for the actual slider code?

Comment: Hey Robert,

I appreciate the response, however, this was several months ago and I have since moved on and no longer recall the exact details of this project. I believe we just opt'd to have it stay as a static layout.

Comment: Just so you know for the future, never, ever use the email/ encrypted password credentials with client side scripting. Always use a server side proxy to return the xml data to the client.